# Atoms animation - which technology

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I would like to make an animation of Molecular diffusion. I have some CSV or binary files with data to create 3D scene with atoms.

- It has to be fast animation with
  diffrent camera views
- transparency vary depends on atom's
  energy

Since I code in C# on a regular basis I am going to pick up XNA (later Mono.XNA, running on linux is a nice have). It does not have to be C#.

Is it the best fit? I would like to reduce the time of making button, scrollbars etc.

Is there anything good that reduce the amout of code? Has anyone had problem with porting XNA animation to Mono.XNA?

Comment: What kinds of primitives will you be using - just spheres?  Will you need lines or cylinders or something even more complex?

Comment: I don't know all the details but I think won't be complex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use XNA for your 3D view, but do your controls in WinForms. App Hub (Microsoft) has a very good example of [using XNA with WinForms](http://create.msdn.com/sample/winforms_series1) ([part 2](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)). This way you have a great API for 3D graphics, and a great API for making interfaces (without having to bend one API to do both things).

My impression of Mono.XNA is that it is hopelessly incomplete. It also doesn't get updated much ([patch list](http://code.google.com/p/monoxna/source/list)). Here is the (at time of writing) current version of a fairly critical class for doing 3D graphics: [GraphicsDevice.cs](http://code.google.com/p/monoxna/source/browse/trunk/src/Microsoft.Xna.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsDevice.cs?r=334) - note the `NotImplementedException`s thrown by all the `Draw*` functions necessary for 3D drawing.

There are a few cross-platform XNA APIs around (I even wrote one of them), and none of them are yet usable for 3D. Maybe one day.

If you really must have Linux support, then it may be worthwhile to use [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) for your graphics. The downside of OpenTK is that it is nowhere near as well supported or easy to use as XNA.

I would recommend that you do your very best to avoid having to use (or worse still, create) a GUI library on a 3D graphics platform (XNA or OpenTK). There is a reason that most of the existing libraries are poorly supported or abandoned. I am under the impression that [Mono's implementation of WinForms](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms) is quite good these days, and there's [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp), if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried porting an XNA application to Mono, but I have used several different GUI libraries, and I can honestly say that Tom Shane's [Neoforce](http://neoforce.codeplex.com/) library is the best. Unfortunately he has ceased updating it, but he did release a version that works with 4.0.